# I am facing an awkward ArrayList index out bounds exception in java

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am attempting to code a library management program in Java. I am facing a problem with ArrayList here. It seems like there is a problem with the integer `i` that I want to use as a variable index, but I don't understand the problem. I have provided the code below.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

// Create a library management system which is capable of issuing books to the students.
// Book should have info like:
// 1. Book name
// 2. Book Author
// 3. Issued to
// 4. Issued on
// User should be able to add books, return issued books, issue books.
// Assume that all the users are registered with their names in the central database.

class library{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Long> phone_no = new ArrayList<>();
    
    int i = 0;
    public void registration(){
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        this.name.add(this.i,sc.next());
        
        System.out.print("Enter your phone no.: ");
        this.phone_no.add(this.i,sc.nextLong());
        
        this.i++;
    }

    

    public void registrationdetails(){
        System.out.printf("Your name: %s\nYour phone no.: %ld",this.name.get(this.i),this.phone_no.get(this.i));
    }

    // public void issuebook() {
    //     System.out.println("Enter the name of the book: ");
    //     String bookname = sc.next();
    //     System.out.println("Enter the name of the book: ");
    //     String bookauthor = sc.next();
    //     System.out.println("Enter the name of the book: ");
    //     String issuedto = sc.next();
    //     System.out.println("Enter the name of the book: ");
    //     LocalDate issuedon = LocalDate.parse(sc.next());
    // }


    
}

public class Library_management {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        library Anish = new library();
        Anish.registration();
        Anish.registrationdetails();

    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Enter your name: ijfwoa
Enter your phone no.: 456
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
        at library.registrationdetails(Library_management.java:34)
        at Library_management.main(Library_management.java:57)
```

I can't understand what the problem is. Please help me.

Comment: Minor tip, always name Classes in uppercase and no underscores, just convention. (i.e class library -> class Library). Same for your second class - should be renamed to LibraryManagement. Methods should be named in camelcase (i.e registrationdetails -> registrationDetails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your indexing in library.registrationdetails()

```
System.out.printf("Your name: %s\nYour phone no.: %ld",this.name.get(this.i),this.phone_no.get(this.i));
```

when you are doing `this.name.get(this.i)` `this.i` equals to 1. Arrays in Java start at 0, so the index 1 actually refers to the *second** element. At this point in time you only have 1 element in your list so the program fails - you are trying to get the 2nd element in a list with 1 element!

To fix this simply subtract one from the index: (i.e replace the above line with this one in your code)

```
System.out.printf("Your name: %s\nYour phone no.: %ld",this.name.get(this.i-1),this.phone_no.get(this.i-1));
```

Comment: Ok I understand. It was a small mistake. Or I could do i++ after printing the details l. Right??

Comment: @CODERrookie Exactly! Altough which solution you want to take will probably depend on how you choose to progress with this code. Keep both in mind (maybe choose one solution, and keep the other as a comment with a reminder why it's there) then if you run into further problems with this you can switch to the other. If you found my answer suffices, feel free to click the checkmark on the left so this question can be closed off :)

Comment: Thanks It was very helpful.